# Preamp for Sony ECM MS907 mic

Tags: microphone, preamp, sony

I'm pretty new in the audio world, I'll try the best I can to explain.

I recently bought a **[Sony ECM MS907](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/ecm-ms907)**, a capacitor microphone with the idea to do some voice recording and maybe music.

At first, I believed I could just plug it in my computer (it's **3.5 stereo jack**) but I needed to boost the gain of the sound card to **~30 dB**.

Even with this settings, I hardly get the sound coming from more than 30cm of the microphone.

As I looked up the feedbacks, apparently, it much better with Sony recorders (camcorders...).

I suspect a preamp issue. I was hoping to buy some (cheap) headphone USB-powered amplifier. I have found lots of them that do 3.5mm stereo jack that I could use on the go (if I use a battery).

Nonetheless, during my research, I read about phantom power and preamp for mic (not many with 3.5 jack).

What do you think ? Would it work ?

Thanks in advance,

Best

Answer (score 1):

So strange you asked this question 19 days ago. I've had this model in a drawer for 5+ years and only tonight took it out to clean rust from the battery compartment and re-familiarise myself with it.

I think the problem for you is that this model is not sensitive enough for voice recording, at a distance, hence having to boost the gain on your PC.

I've used this mic for recording loud bands and instruments at close range, for that purpose it's brilliant, with no clips or distortion.

I suspect the only way you could use it for the effect you want is to hold it close to your mouth and speak clearly.

For spoken work it is quite quiet even when recording on my Sony MiniDisc MZ-n505 which it is designed to be used with.

You might want to find something more sensitive, or take up sound engineering and out door events recording!

Hope this helps, keep experimenting, maybe it'll work out.

Peace.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
After further researches, my sound card can amplify but the sound is still a little low and noisy at 20/30 dBm.

I'll try with a USB Dual Pre (with the right adapters) to see if it's better.